# Importing an Excel Listobject into an Access table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, listobject

I have an Access database with a table named **InventoryAvail**. I'd like to push a button in Access and import a specific Listobject from a specific Excel file to fill the **InventoryAvail** table.

What vba code do I need to put on the button's event?

`Docmd.Transferspreadsheet` will not work because I do not want all of the data from the spreadsheet, I only want what is in the specific Listobject.

The Excel file is called **Inventory** and resides on my desktop. The worksheet is named **Inventory**.
The Listobject is named **Available** and has two columns: `Part, Qty`.

The **InventoryAvail** table has two columns: `PartNumber` and `Quantity`.

I need the data from the Excel Listobject **Available** to be imported into the Access table **InventoryAvail**

Comment: More details needed - tabledef, Listobject snapshot and description of what goes where? None of these are in your question so it's very hard to form an answer.

Comment: I added a few more details. Let me know if anything else would be helpful.

Comment: What's the worksheet name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that for some reason `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` does not work for named ranges. I was able to hack it once by pulling the address from it, but I had to open the workbook.

In any case I can't see a way around opening the workbook

This should work for you.

**Steps:**

- opens the spreadsheet
- reads the listbox data into an array
- opens recordset using your table
- passes each row of data into the table using `AddNew` method
- cleans up

Here's the code

```
Public Sub AddInventory()

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Const IMPORT_TABLE  As String = "InventoryAvail"

    Const IMPORT_FILE   As String = "yourspreadsheetfullpathname"
    Const SHEET_NAME    As String = "Sheet1"
    Const LISTBOX_NAME  As String = "List1"

    Dim xlApp       As Object
    Dim xlBook      As Object
    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.WorkBooks.Open(IMPORT_FILE, , True) ' open as readonly

    Dim xlList      As Variant
    Dim intRow      As Integer

    ' creates an array from ListObject values
    xlList = xlBook.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME).ListObjects(LISTBOX_NAME).DataBodyRange.Value

    xlBook.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(IMPORT_TABLE)
    With rs
        For intRow = LBound(xlList) To UBound(xlList)
            Debug.Print xlList(intRow, 1) & ": " & xlList(intRow, 2)
            .AddNew
            .Fields(0).Value = xlList(intRow, 1)
            .Fields(1).Value = xlList(intRow, 2)
            .Update
        Next intRow
        .Close
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know only ListObject name, there is no other way except opening Excel file like described in **@dbmitch** answer, but if you know ListObject range, you can transfer the data from this range only to your table without using `Excel.Application` object, just use SELECT like this:

```
INSERT INTO InventoryAvail (PartNumber, Quantity) 
SELECT *
  FROM [Inventory$D3:E24] 
    IN "C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\Inventory.xlsx" [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0];
```

This will work much faster, than thru the object

**UPDATE**

Just figured out, that it's possible to query named ranges by name. Syntax like this:

```
INSERT INTO InventoryAvail (PartNumber, Quantity) 
SELECT *
  FROM [Available] 
    IN "C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\Inventory.xlsx" [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0];
```

Please note, that this syntax works with named ranges, for tables such kind data selection doesn't work. Also won't work a named range if it was assigned to the same range as table. But it's possible to define named range, which includes table range, but not exactly the same

Comment: Nice - so there is absolutely no way to get at a range name without opening Excel?

Comment: It is possible, just indicate named range by name `[$RangeName]`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Nice - that's an EXCELLENT answer - thanks for sharing

Comment: Would I use DoCmd.RunSQL to try that out? Right now I've got:   `sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO InventoryAvail (PartNumber, Quantity) SELECT * FROM [$Available] In 'C:\Users\AHaws\Desktop\Inventory.xlsx'[Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0];"   DoCmd.RunSQL sqlUpdate`   It's giving me an error about not finding the object [$Available], it may be because of my incorrect use of quotations?

Comment: Before using SQL in VBA try this query in Query Bulider (in SQL mode). If it gives error, you have problem with syntax

Comment: I set up a little test worksheet. This works: `SELECT * FROM [A1:B4] In "C:\Users\AHaws\Desktop\TestBook.xlsx" [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0];`     However, this doesn't 'SELECT * FROM [$Test] In "C:\Users\AHaws\Desktop\TestBook.xlsx" [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0];'

Comment: `Test` in your Excel file is Table or Named Range? I tested for Named Range

Comment: I added a note to the answer

Comment: Ah `Test` is a table or ListObject name. Thanks for adding that note to the answer.